# PCB hybrid stackup

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

Have you seen or is it advisable to use TEFLON (PTFE) material between signal and ground layer and use an aluminum core material for better heat dissipation? I am improving a 6 layer circuit board with 30MHz analog signal and high power dissipation.

Comment: Can I ask how much power is "high power"?  Much better to have a number than a subjective description.

Comment: I agree my phrasing was bad: It is around 300mW per channel for 8 channels. But it is for photodiode circuit and I am placing the chips close to the photodiode to reduce parasitics, so I am concern about the heat.

Answer (score 1):

30MHz would not need teflon (rogers 4003 or whatever). You will get worse heat dissipation if the core is teflon as teflon has poor thermal conductivity. Copper is also a better thermal conductor. So it would not be wise to use teflon and aluminum as a PCB substrate if you want thermal conductivity for heat dissipation.

A better way would be to use more copper on more layers or increase the copper weight on a layer with thermal copper (like use 2oz or 1.5oz) and allow room for heat spreading. A heatsink also goes a long way to get rid of heat.

Comment: "it would not be wise to use teflon and aluminum as a PCB substrate if you want thermal conductivity for heat dissipation." -- I thought aluminum was good for heat dissipation, do you mean FR-4 and teflon?

Comment: Copper is better for heat dissipation. If you have a aluminum substrate, that is different, as far as I'm aware the aluminum substrates are two layer PCB's